# Read local plain text file with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I have a text file containing some logging data from another (C++) application. As I don't want to use some GUI framework just to display some visual analysis of the logging data, I want to use HTML and Javascript to do this task.

I managed to input the data via a file input `<input id="inputfile" type="file"/>` and then read the file via `FileReader` in Javascript.

My question: the logging file is in the same directory as the HTML+JS files and always has the same filename, it would be nice to read the file without having the user select the same file over and over again.
I could not manage to do this. I tried `<object id="data" type="text/plain" data="out.txt"></object>` to include the logging file in the HTML and then read it via JS, but without success.

Any ideas on how to avoid the user selection and always read the same (static) file when loading the document? 
If possible:
(a.) by just using HTML, Javascript and jQuery. (b.) without having to specify an absolute file path.

There is another answer using XMLHttpRequest. But as I said, I need a relative path and my data is plain text.

Comment: we cant go to prev dir if all are in one dir or child , then can read using XMLHttpRequest, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106436/3551786) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11053777/3551786)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not select a file with javascript without human interaction for security reasons but you can include in using a hidden `iframe` and then read the content of file like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframeId" src="data.text" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <script>
      function readText() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var text = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerText;
        console.log(text);
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        readText();
      }, 50);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**this will do the job but i am not sure if this is the best way to do it**